# ListView Custom Adapter error on scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have attached my code below of custom adapter of `listView` but when I am scrolling the list I got:

> mView does not exist, so discard the remaining points.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>   Can anybody help why I am getting this error it would be very helpfull

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = TransactionAdapter.class.getName();
    List<Transacation> arrlist;
    Context c;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context, List<Transacation> list) {
        this.arrlist = list;
        this.c = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.c);
    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrlist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View result;
            final MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
            final Transacation transacation = arrlist.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_adapter, parent,
                        false);

                myViewHolder.tv_date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
                myViewHolder.tv_status = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
                myViewHolder.tv_expiry = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_expiry);
                myViewHolder.tv_amount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);

                result = convertView;
                convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);

            } else {
                result = convertView;
            }

            //        myViewHolder.tv_date.setText(""+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM").format(new java.util.Date (transacation.date)));
            if(transacation.transactionType.equals("CREDIT")){
                myViewHolder.tv_status.setText("Wallet Credited");
                myViewHolder.tv_expiry.setText("Expires on " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(new java.util.Date (transacation.expiry_date)));
                myViewHolder.tv_amount.setText("+₹" + transacation.n_amount);
                myViewHolder.tv_amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#23DD47"));

            }
            else{
                myViewHolder.tv_status.setText("Wallet Expired");
                myViewHolder.tv_expiry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myViewHolder.tv_amount.setText("-₹" + transacation.n_amount);
                myViewHolder.tv_amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FB5151"));

            }

            return convertView;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder {
            TextView tv_date;
            TextView tv_status;
            TextView tv_expiry;
            TextView tv_amount;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please use AutoCompleteTextview with Custom Adapter

Comment: please upload exact error log from logcat

Comment: 2020-04-10 10:46:47.022 24571-24571/com.example.zingbus E/ViewRootImpl: mView does not exist, so discard the remaining points. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference 
After this my whole list got disappear

Comment: see this one for refrence https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the ViewHolder when the convertView is not null by getting the tag back, so change your `getView()` to be:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View result;
    final MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
    final Transacation transacation = arrlist.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_adapter, parent,
                false);
        myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder()
        myViewHolder.tv_date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        myViewHolder.tv_status = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        myViewHolder.tv_expiry = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_expiry);
        myViewHolder.tv_amount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);

        result = convertView;
        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);

    } else {
        result = convertView;
        myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //        myViewHolder.tv_date.setText(""+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM").format(new java.util.Date (transacation.date)));
    if(transacation.transactionType.equals("CREDIT")){
        myViewHolder.tv_status.setText("Wallet Credited");
        myViewHolder.tv_expiry.setText("Expires on " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(new java.util.Date (transacation.expiry_date)));
        myViewHolder.tv_amount.setText("+₹" + transacation.n_amount);
        myViewHolder.tv_amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#23DD47"));

    }
    else{
        myViewHolder.tv_status.setText("Wallet Expired");
        myViewHolder.tv_expiry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myViewHolder.tv_amount.setText("-₹" + transacation.n_amount);
        myViewHolder.tv_amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FB5151"));

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion please check if the findViewById has the correct Id name or if nothing to do with it please update from

```
myViewHolder.tv_amount.setText("+₹" + transacation.n_amount);
```

to

```
myViewHolder.tv_amount.setText("+₹" + String.ValueOf(transacation.n_amount));
```

or please post full Log value